# Getting: Could not connect to Server - Connectin refused with postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, window, pgadmin

I have Postgres 13 and pgAdmin installed on my Windows machine. It worked for like ~six month, until I hat do restart my machine. After restarting the computer (which I had not *done* because there was an update), I am trying to connect to Postgres via pgAdmin as always and I get this

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Some answeres on stackoverflow suggest, to edit the `postgresql.conf` file which I a) do not find in my postgres installation and b) I think is not the correct solution for me because it worked without any problem until I restarted my machine.

Why is that? It feels like postgres is not starting? Although this is a wild guess...

Comment: Is postresql service running?   Has the firewall entry been reset?

Comment: @ewong How can I check if a postgres service is running. I have not resetted the firewall, unless windows did that automatically after the restart...

Comment: Control Panel->Administrator Tools->Services

Comment: @ewong Is there a command line to execute this? I cannot find it in my preferences... https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/client-management/administrative-tools-in-windows-10

Comment: You'll need to find the name of the service, then do ```net start <servicename>```.  That's the extent of my knowledge.

Comment: @ewong grrr. I hate windows. Everything looks in every version different and is located in another place.

Comment: yeah.. know what you mean.  If you do need more help, perhaps Serverfault might help

Comment: You almost surely have a postgresql.conf, you just need to look harder.  But editing it won't help if you don't know what to change.  Look for the log files, probably in `c:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/data/log/`.  Did it even attempt to start up after the reboot, and if so why did it fail?